# Way to check if any object in ICollection have the same ID value

Tags: c#, icollection

I have an Object that is a ICollection type() . I want to check in this object if there are same ID values. If there's same ID i want that a property of two different item are merged.

how i can make it?

Comment: `ICollection<T>` doesn't have an ID property.  So I assume your T type has the ID.  Are you just looking to iterate through the collection and then combine two items in the collection?  Please explain what you are looking for in more detail.  You can't change a collection while iterating through it, but there are plenty of articles on that here.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make some assumptions about your specific case.  But assuming the data type stored in your ICollection looks something like this.

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use some linq and do something like this.

```
List<Data> data = new List<Data>
{
        new Data { ID = 0, Value = 3.2m },
        new Data { ID = 1, Value = 6.9m },
        new Data { ID = 2, Value = 9.4m },
        new Data { ID = 3, Value = 2.1m },
        new Data { ID = 4, Value = 8.4m },
        new Data { ID = 5, Value = 1.1m },
        new Data { ID = 0, Value = 6.8m }
};

List<Data> dupe = (
    from d in data
    group d by d.ID into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select new Data { ID = g.Key, Value = g.Select(v => v.Value).Sum() }).ToList();

data.RemoveAll(d => dupe.Select(v => v.ID).Contains(d.ID));
data.AddRange(dupe);
```